# How do I use the ODBC API bcp_bind with DATETIME column?

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, bcp

I am trying to bulk copy data using the ODBC bcp extensions into a SQL Server 2008 R2 table with a DATETIME column. Is there a practical way of converter from the common C/C++ structs `time_t` or `struct tm` to the DBDATETIME struct.

It is defined as the unwieldy:

```
typedef struct dbdatetime
{                       // Internal representation of DATETIME data type
    LONG  dtdays;       // No of days since Jan-1-1900 (maybe negative)
    ULONG dttime;       // No. of 300 hundredths of a second since midnight
} DBDATETIME;
```

Which requires data massaging before the call to bcp_sendrow. It would be nice if I could push the conversion load to the server rather than onto my app.

Even being able to do something like this would be nice:

```
const char* charDT= "1923-11-21 06:50:40";
bcp_bind(hdlDbc, (LPCBYTE) charDT, 0, sizeof(DBDATETIME), 0, 0, SQLDATETIME, 11)
```

But I get errors on the bcp_sendrow "Invalid Data for Column". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const char* charDT= "19231121 06:50:40";

bcp_bind(hdlDbc, (LPCBYTE)charDT, 0, SQL_VARLEN_DATA, (LPCBYTE)pTerminator, iLenTerminator, SQLVARCHAR, 11);
```